# Loops as synonyms to handles or straps

Tags: meaning-in-context

From the sitcom [Seinfeld](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seinfeld), they were describing a bra in the sentence *"You got the cups in the front, two **loops** in the back"*.

It seems that in this context "loops" means "straps". Is that correct?

What are other uses of "loops" with the same meaning? General straps like bag handles?

Is it a plural noun and can it be used in the singular form (without the ending "s")?

---

I don't know if these sources break copyrights, so I don't know how long they will last, but searching for the whole sentence we can find transcripts and videos to that episode, like:

- Transcript: http://www.seinfeldscripts.com/TheSniffingAccountant.htm
- Video (go to the point 2:30): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3AMRHXMfjs

**EDIT:** Added a picture of the sitcom scene. Frank was hanging the bra while he would analyze and describe it.

[image: Frank was hanging the bra while he would analyze and describe it]

Comment: Citations are do not infringe copyright. When you click on the link, you have to go there.There is no infringement. Rest assured.

Comment: Please see my answer. Loops are not straps. Loops are lazos and straps are alzas, if you speak Spanish.

Comment: @Lambie Along to my research, the answers and comments were so helpful, and I had already concluded that "laços" and "alças" were the respective translations to Portuguese, that I see now have matches to Spanish with similar spelling.

Comment: É uma pena que nemhuma mulher tenha respondido. Nenhuma mulher chamaria essas alças de laços. Nenhuma. Por isso mesmo é tão engraçado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the *straps* of the brassiere form *loops*.  A "loop" is a particular circular shape, while a *strap* is a piece of cloth used to attach or hold down something.  They are not synonyms.

As in any language, English humor is often based on how certain words sound in context.  "Loop" is a funny-sounding word, plus, since George's father is dismissively describing the *shape* of the bra rather than the *function*, it adds to the overall absurdity of the situation.

"Loop" is a singular noun.  You can have a single *loop*, or multiple *loops*. It is also a verb, in that something can *loop* around something else, like a [string when tying a knot](https://www.netknots.com/fishing_knots/perfection-loop).

[image]

Many other things form *loops*: bag handles, neckties, some earrings, certain types of pasta or cereal, etc.  You can say that the orbit of the Moon forms *loops* around the Earth, and the Earth forms *loops* around the Sun.  A happy dog can *run loops* around its owner.  Airplanes can do an acrobatic maneuver called a [loop-de-loop](https://youtu.be/KMRAJWmkzNA?t=148).  And so on.

(Edit) in response to Lambie's objection:  The scene isn't funny because "men are clueless".  *Seinfeld*'s humor was rarely that straightforward -- in the episodes where they did talk about how men know little about women, that was the premise of the running joke, not the punchline.

My interpretation is that George's father uses "loops" as a kind of dismissive oversimplification, because his ego was hurt from being wrong about what bras are made of.  The overall scene is funny because of the absurdity of the family getting so argumentative over *bras*.

Note that Larry David, who co-wrote and co-produced *Seinfeld*, was the inspiration for the character of George Costanza.  Judging from the kind of humor in his other shows, it's entirely likely that scenes like this happened frequently in his family.

Comment: Great answer. I've noticed that you used the word *brassiere*. Is it really used in conversation? Does it sound "fancy" or pretentious?

Comment: "Brassiere" is probably more *formal*, if anything, and does make it sound somewhat more *fancy* or possibly *old-fashioned* (although George's mother's brassiere is probably as unsexy as the garment can be)  In casual conversation you would just say "bra".

Comment: There are no loops on the typical bra. That's why it's funny. "Men are clueless" about bras. Brassiere is outdated and rather quaint. Women say bra.

Answer (score 1):

The definition in [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/loop) is "*the curved shape made when something long and thin, such as a piece of string, bends until one part of it nearly touches or crosses another part of it*".

This definition  describes physical loops, but the term is also used with an extended mathematical meaning of "a closed path". See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(topology) and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(computing) as specific examples. Also consider [this SE question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334114/why-are-circuits-considered-loops) about electricity.

With this in mind, a bra can indeed be seen as having two loops in the back. The loops are formed by the straps and the caps. It is an unusual description, and it may be funny (especially for people who are familiar with the mathematical meaning) in a non-mathematical context.

Shopping bag handles also *form* loops (with the bag), but they are not loops in and of themselves. Loop, straps and handles are not synonymous.

And yes, loop is also used in singular.

Answer (score 0):

"You got the cups in the front, two loops in the back".

I do not want to view the video, so I don't know which character is talking.

BUT: it is a man. Ok,I see the other answer says George's father. He is clueless. :)

Anyway, that is a misuse, and funny too,of the word loop.

Bra straps are not loops. They go from the top of the front over the shoulders ending at the top of back of the bra on a woman's back.

It's actually very funny. A "typical man" not knowing how to describe a bra.

There are loops in the previous answer's image. :)

Bras have straps, or, they are strapless bras.

Comment: You should probably watch the video.  He's holding a bra in his hands as he describes it.

Comment: @Andrew As I said, and now I have seen it, bras don't have loops. There is nothing that is a loop or that loops on a bra, **which is why it is so funny**. A guy like his father can't describe a bra. A loop is length of some material (metal, rubber, cloth or whatever) that must have at least one cross-over point. We need some native English speakers here who are women....and I am sorry to say that no bra is built with any kind of loop at all. Just try asking any female friend or family member....